# after upgrade Magento 2.3.4 to 2.4 product can't save , showing error

Tags: magento, magento2

I have upgraded magento to 2.4 while save product it showing error.
I have try update on schedule, setup upgrade, cache clean reindex, given root user permission, but still get this issue on product save.

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'm24.scconnector_google_feed_cl' doesn't exist, query was: DELETE FROM `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` WHERE (value_id = 630 AND entity_id = 640 AND store_id = 0)
```

I have tried below commands:

```
php bin/magento cron:install
php bin/magento cron:run
php bin/magento index:reindex
mysql -u root -p set global log_bin_trust_function_creators=1;
php bin/magento module:disable Magento_GoogleShoppingAds
```

I can't found table 'scconnector_google_feed_cl'.

can anyone tell why this table not showing after migrate from Magento 2.3.4 to 2.4?

Can anyone give me the SQL query for creating table scconnector_google_feed_cl so I can create it?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Did you update using Composer? tried composer update?

Comment: I'm running into the exact same issue. Using composer update does not fix it. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 4):

As I posted [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/326116):

> It was used in module Magento_GoogleShoppingAds but that module is end
> of life.
>
> https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/sales-channels/google-eol.html
>
> However, the module adds triggers to your MySQL database and
> sometimes, when you upgrade to e.g. Magento 2.3.6 the module, removes
> the table but fails to remove the triggers.
>
> I had to run show triggers in my DB and then I had to drop the
> triggers before I could save product again.
>
> ```
> drop trigger trg_catalog_product_website_after_insert;
> drop trigger trg_catalog_product_website_after_update;
> drop trigger trg_catalog_product_website_after_delete;
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_after_insert;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_after_update;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_after_delete;
```

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This provided answer could benefit from an explanation. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers. From [Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/27298384).